# How do I get company names that individuals work for on Linkedin using python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I'm writing code to scrap data from sites like LinkedIn and in the process of doing so, I wasn't able to extract the company name even though I'd followed through on the expected format of using XPATH's inbuilt class nodes.

I tried the following line of code to scrap the company name from each profile:

```
company=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="pv-text-details_right-panel"]').text
```

It produced no error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this xpath:

```
(//ul[@class='pv-text-details__right-panel']//div)[1]
```

Comment: Try to add documentation and other links so others can prove your answer is correct. This can help future users. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I tried an alternate line of code as well where I used the CSS_SELECTOR function to produce a line of code like this : #    next_lnk = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.d6cvqb a[id="pnnext"]')